# Dialog Box Delay / Not Displayed Fully for 2 Seconds While Application is Starting Up

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, controls

I am new to Winforms development and I do not see a solution yet on Stackoverflow, but may have missed it.

I have a dialog box that comes up, but due to application startup processing, it is only half displayed for the first 2 seconds or so (i.e. shows border and the background except where controls will be shown). The control locations are white until controls are displayed after that initial 2 seconds.

I understand I could put a delay in the application while it is starting up, but would prefer something like a `Suspend()` / `Resume()` pair in strategic locations. I have tried putting in the load event, but that had no effect. Also, it looks like `Refresh()` breaks the Suspend/Resume. Ideas appreciated since I would like to use this strategy elsewhere in the application as well. I am wondering what is an approach that will work for this and other areas that flicker badly (or outright show a long delay before fully displaying like this startup dialog box as described).

Comment: Where is the code located that is causing the delay?

Comment: In the Shown event handler of the Main Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your long-running code in the `Load` event handler instead.  By putting it in the `Shown` event handler, it causes the form to freeze until it's done loading because the shown event handler is not letting other events in the message loop, e.g. the `Paint` event -- get processed.  At least if you put it in the `Load` event, all the long running code will occur before anything gets displayed at all.

If you don't like having any delay, consider putting the long running code in a timer that kicks off in the `Shown` event.

Then there's always the `BackgroundWorker` if you want to get more advanced with long-running code.